# Creating a Function to assign a value to a pick e.g 1 is 100 and 2 is 99 etc... And then finding the sum by a variable

Tags: r

I have a draft list of players with positions and pick numbers. I want to create a function that would assign to the first 100 picks. With 1 being 100, 2 being 99 etc... And then I want the sum of that value by position.

(Redraft Data Frame at the Bottom)

```
positional_value <- function(position) {
  position <- deparse(substitute(position))
  first_100 <- Redraft %>% 
    select(Position, Pick) %>% 
    filter(Pick <= 100)
  pick_value <- ((first_100 * 100) / first_100) - first_100
  pick_final <- inner_join(first_100, pick_value)
  pick_total <- pick_final %>% 
    select(Position, pick_value) %>% 
    filter(Position = position) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(pick_value))
 return(total)
}
```

And I get a

```
Error: Can't join on 'Position' x 'Position' because of incompatible types (factor / logical)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(left, right) :
 Error: Can't join on 'Position' x 'Position' because of incompatible types (factor / logical)
```

when I try it with QB

Heres the data frame:

```
structure(list(Pick = 1:384, Name = structure(c(12L, 14L, 1L, 
2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 
13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 
15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 
17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 
7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 
9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 
5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 
19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 
10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 
14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 
13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 
8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 
6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 
6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 
8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 
13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 
14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 
10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 
19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 
5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 
2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 
20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 
18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 
14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 
8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L), .Label = c("Blake", "Connor", 
"Dakota", "FFB", "Fitz", "Haydon", "Isaac", "Jack", "Jackson", 
"Jacob", "Jacob H", "Javi", "Jeremy", "Justin", "Nick", "Pete", 
"Sam", "Simon", "Tucker", "Will"), class = "factor"), Team = structure(c(30L, 
10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 
11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 
12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 
25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 
8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 
13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 
15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 
22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 
20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 
18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 
18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 
20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 
22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 
15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 
13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 
8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 
5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 
19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 
14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 
30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 
9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 
26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 
26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 
9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 
10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 
11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 
12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 
25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 
8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L), .Label = c("49ers", 
"Bears", "Bengals", "Bills", "Broncos", "Browns", "Buccaneers", 
"Cardinals", "Chargers", "Chiefs", "Colts", "Cowboys", "Dolphins", 
"Eagles", "Falcons", "Giants", "Jaguars", "Jets", "Lions", "Packers", 
"Panthers", "Patriots", "Raiders", "Rams", "Ravens", "Redskins", 
"Saints", "Seahawks", "Steelers", "Texans", "Titans", "Vikings"
), class = "factor"), Round = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
    Pos.. = structure(c(49L, 60L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
    27L, 76L, 43L, 50L, 51L, 92L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 77L, 56L, 
    57L, 58L, 89L, 59L, 85L, 61L, 103L, 3L, 106L, 35L, 62L, 36L, 
    63L, 42L, 10L, 107L, 18L, 64L, 108L, 65L, 109L, 19L, 11L, 
    110L, 86L, 37L, 111L, 12L, 20L, 112L, 66L, 21L, 38L, 13L, 
    90L, 78L, 81L, 30L, 14L, 15L, 82L, 39L, 16L, 17L, 93L, 94L, 
    4L, 22L, 95L, 96L, 2L, 97L, 67L, 5L, 68L, 87L, 83L, 84L, 
    6L, 31L, 44L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 7L, 28L, 101L, 32L, 29L, 8L, 
    33L, 88L, 69L, 79L, 102L, 9L, 104L, 40L, 23L, 24L, 105L, 
    25L, 45L, 80L, 46L, 26L, 47L, 91L, 48L, 34L, 41L, 113L, 114L, 
    115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 
    125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
    135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 137L, 142L, 143L, 
    144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 
    154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 
    164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 
    174L, 175L, 178L, 177L, 176L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
    184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
    194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 
    204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 
    214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "C1", 
    "CB1", "CB10", "CB11", "CB12", "CB13", "CB14", "CB15", "CB2", 
    "CB3", "CB4", "CB5", "CB6", "CB7", "CB8", "CB9", "DE1", "DE2", 
    "DE3", "DE4", "DE5", "DE6", "DE7", "DE8", "DE9", "DT1", "DT2", 
    "DT3", "FS1", "FS2", "FS3", "FS4", "FS5", "LB1", "LB2", "LB3", 
    "LB4", "LB5", "LB6", "LB7", "LG1", "LT1", "LT2", "LT3", "LT4", 
    "LT5", "LT6", "QB1", "QB10", "QB11", "QB12", "QB13", "QB14", 
    "QB15", "QB16", "QB17", "QB18", "QB19", "QB2", "QB20", "QB21", 
    "QB22", "QB23", "QB24", "QB25", "QB26", "QB27", "QB28", "QB3", 
    "QB4", "QB5", "QB6", "QB7", "QB8", "QB9", "RB1", "RB2", "RB3", 
    "RB4", "RG1", "RT1", "RT2", "RT3", "SS1", "SS2", "SS3", "SS4", 
    "TE1", "TE2", "TE3", "WR1", "WR10", "WR11", "WR12", "WR13", 
    "WR14", "WR15", "WR16", "WR17", "WR18", "WR19", "WR2", "WR20", 
    "WR21", "WR3", "WR4", "WR5", "WR6", "WR7", "WR8", "WR9", 
    "WR22", "LT7", "RT4", "DT4", "CB16", "WR23", "WR24", "LT8", 
    "CB17", "CB18", "LT9", "SS5", "LT10", "CB19", "FS6", "WR25", 
    "FS7", "RG2", "CB20", "LT11", "WR26", "DE10", "WR28", "WR29", 
    "WR30", "TE4", "LG2", "DT5", "RT5", "WR31", "RG3", "CB21", 
    "LB8", "CB22", "WR32", "CB23", "LB9", "WR33", "CB24", "TE5", 
    "LB10", "DE11", "TE6", "CB25", "CB26", "DT6", "DT7", "LB11", 
    "WR34", "SS6", "WR35", "FS8", "LT12", "LB12", "FS9", "WR36", 
    "RG4", "RB5", "FS10", "RB6", "WR37", "CB27", "CB28", "DT8", 
    "WR38", "DE12", "CB29", "FS11", "WR39", "LB13", "WR40", "RT6", 
    "C2", "CB30", "WR41", "WR42", "LG3", "SS7", "DE13", "LT13", 
    "DE14", "RT7", "WR43", "RB7", "LB14", "WR44", "DE15", "FS12", 
    "FS13", "FS14", "RB8", "LB15", "LT14", "LT15", "DE16", "RT8", 
    "FS15", "LB16", "LT16", "DE17", "LB17", "C3", "C4", "CB31", 
    "RB9", "CB32"), class = "factor"), Player = structure(c(87L, 
    91L, 72L, 38L, 14L, 24L, 79L, 78L, 3L, 57L, 90L, 70L, 107L, 
    31L, 39L, 10L, 56L, 68L, 20L, 4L, 94L, 93L, 45L, 52L, 51L, 
    44L, 80L, 97L, 62L, 67L, 40L, 98L, 101L, 89L, 50L, 9L, 85L, 
    104L, 19L, 41L, 109L, 58L, 106L, 81L, 37L, 26L, 29L, 27L, 
    18L, 86L, 60L, 84L, 17L, 74L, 105L, 95L, 111L, 63L, 76L, 
    55L, 92L, 110L, 12L, 15L, 64L, 96L, 34L, 25L, 61L, 103L, 
    54L, 21L, 53L, 49L, 59L, 108L, 71L, 83L, 77L, 82L, 102L, 
    7L, 65L, 2L, 69L, 32L, 22L, 75L, 43L, 5L, 8L, 46L, 35L, 42L, 
    23L, 88L, 6L, 11L, 60L, 48L, 16L, 13L, 30L, 36L, 73L, 33L, 
    99L, 28L, 100L, 66L, 47L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 
    118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
    128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
    139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 
    149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 
    159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 
    169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 
    179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 
    189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 
    199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 
    209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
    219L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A.J. Brown", "Aaron Donald", 
    "Aaron Rodgers", "Adoree' Jackson", "Allen Robinson", "Amari Cooper", 
    "Anthony Harris", "Antonio Brown", "Baker Mayfield", "Bobby Wagner", 
    "Byron Jones ", "Cameron Jordan", "Carson Wentz", "Casey Hayward", 
    "CeDee Lamb", "Chandler Jones", "Chase Young", "Chris Godwin", 
    "Christian McCaffrey", "Cooper Kupp", "Courtland Sutton", 
    "D.J. Moore", "Dak Prescott", "Danielle Hunter", "Darius Leonard", 
    "Darius Slay", "Darren Waller", "DaVante Adams", "David Bakhtiari", 
    "DeAndre Hopkins", "Deforest Buckner", "Demarcus Lawrence", 
    "Denzel Ward", "Derek Carr", "Derrick Henry", "Derwin James", 
    "Deshaun Watson", "Drew Brees", "Drew Lock", "Dwayne Haskins", 
    "Ezekiel Elliott", "Fletcher Cox", "Gardner Minshew", "George Kittle", 
    "Harrison Smith", "Isaiah Simmons", "J.J. Watt", "Jaire Alexander", 
    "Jalen Ramsey", "Jamal Adams", "Jared Goff", "Jarrett Stidham", 
    "Jason Kelce", "Jeffrey Okudah", "Jimmy Garappolo", "Joe Burrow", 
    "Joey Bosa", "Jordan Love", "Josh Allen", "Juju Smith-Schuster", 
    "Julio Jones", "Justin Simmons", "Keenan Allen", "Kenny Golladay", 
    "Kevin Byard", "Khalil Mack", "Kirk Cousins", "Kyle Fuller", 
    "Kyler Murray ", "La'el Collins", "Lamar Jackson ", "Laremy Tunsil", 
    "Marcus Peters", "Marcus Williams", "Marlon Humphrey", "Marshon Lattimore", 
    "Matt Ryan", "Matthew Stafford", "Michael Thomas", "Mike Evans", 
    "Minkah Fitzpatrick", "Mitchell Schwartz ", "Myles Garrett", 
    "Nick Bosa", "Odell Beckham Jr.", "Patrick Mahomes ", "Patrick Peterson", 
    "Quenton Nelson", "Ronnie Stanley", "Russell Wilson ", "Ryan Ramczyk", 
    "Ryan Tannehill", "Sam Darnold", "Saquon Barkley", "Stefon Diggs", 
    "Stephon Gilmore", "T.J. Watt", "Taylor Decker", "Taylor Lewan", 
    "Teddy Bridgewater", "Terron Armstead", "Terry McLaurin", 
    "Tom Brady", "Travis Kelce", "Tre White", "Tua Tagovailoa", 
    "Tyrann Mathieu", "Tyreek Hill", "Von Miller", "Zack Martin", 
    "Calvin Ridley", "Tyron Smith", "Lane Johnson", "Derrick Brown", 
    "Desmond King", "Adam Thielen", "Jerry Jeudy", "Jake Matthews", 
    "J.C. Jackson", "Richard Sherman", "Trent Williams", "Landon Collins", 
    "Andrew Thomas", "Xavien Howard", "Eddie Jackson", "Tyler Lockett", 
    "Adrian Amos", "Brandon Scherff", "Jamal Dean", "Anthony Castonzo", 
    "Devante Parker", "Jadeveon Clownye", "Jadeveon Clowney", 
    "K.J. Hamler", "Jameson Crowder", "Marquise Brown", "Zach Ertz", 
    "Joe Thuney", "Grady Jarrett", "Orlando Brown Jr.", "Tyler Boyd", 
    "D.K. Metcalf", "David Decastro", "Chris Harris Jr.", "Shaq Barrett", 
    "Quinton Dunbar", "DJ Chark Jr.", "Steven Nelson", "Demario Davis", 
    "Deebo Samuel", "Shaquill Griffin", "Mark Andrews", "Deion Jones", 
    "Marcus Davenport", "Dallas Goedert", "Charvarius Ward", 
    "D.J. Hayden", "Kenny Clark", "Chris Jones", "Roquan Smith", 
    "Henry Ruggs III", "Keanu Neal", "Brandin Cooks", "Micah Hyde", 
    "Isaiah Wynn", "Za'Darius Smith", "Justin Reid", "Michael Gallup", 
    "Shaq Mason", "Alvin Kamara", "Budda Baker", "Joe Mixon", 
    "Robert Woods", "James Bradberry", "Nickell Robey-Coleman", 
    "Arik Armstead", "Jalen Reagor", "Jonathan Allen", "Carlton Davis", 
    "Earl Thomas", "T.Y. Hilton", "Patrick Queen", "A.J. Green", 
    "Tristan Wirfs", "Frank Ragnow", "Brian Poole", "Darius Slayton", 
    "Justin Jefferson", "Joel Bitonio", "Kareem Jackson", "Trey Flowers", 
    "Bryan Bulaga", "Bradley Chubb", "Taylor Moton", "Jarvis Landry", 
    "Leonard Fournette", "Eric Kendricks", "John Ross", "Maxx Crosby", 
    "Xavier McKinney", "Juan Thornhill", "Jordan Poyer", "Dalvin Cook", 
    "Bud Dupree", "Alejandro Villanueva", "Kolton Miller", "Dee Ford", 
    "Jack Conklin", "Kyle Dugger", "Preston Smith", "Mekhi Becton", 
    "Dante Fowler Jr.", "Jordan Jenkins", "Eric McCoy", "Ryan Jenson", 
    "Jonathan Jones", "Derrius Guice", "DJ Reed Jr."), class = "factor"), 
    Position = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 14L, 10L, 16L, 3L, 16L, 7L, 10L, 
    7L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 16L, 4L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 16L, 4L, 3L, 16L, 
    14L, 7L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 
    6L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 
    2L, 16L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 3L, 5L, 16L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 14L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 3L, 
    16L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 15L, 9L, 6L, 
    7L, 16L, 9L, 13L, 5L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 
    9L, 3L, 6L, 16L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 9L, 16L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    15L, 8L, 5L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 12L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 7L, 
    16L, 3L, 15L, 7L, 4L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 16L, 14L, 
    16L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 16L, 12L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 16L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 16L, 7L, 16L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 
    8L, 14L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 16L, 11L, 7L, 16L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "C", "CB", "DE", "DT", 
    "FS", "LB", "LG", "LT", "QB", "RB", "RG", "RT", "SS", "TE", 
    "WR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 384L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm quite new at this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you want `Position == position` rather than `Position = position` inside your call to `filter`

Comment: yes thank you, I fixed the other problems too. But definitely a help!

Comment: Also, note that you can pair all numbers from 1 to 100 like 100 + 1, 99 + 2, 98 + 3 ... so the answer will always be 5050 (50 * 101)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, that allows for a vector of `Position`'s and for other values of picks.

```
positional_value <- function(position, P = 100L, X = Redraft) {
  X %>% 
    filter(Position %in% position, Pick <= P) %>%
    select(Position, Pick) %>% 
    group_by(Position) %>%
    mutate(pick_value = P - Pick + 1L,
           PickTotal = sum(pick_value)) %>%
    ungroup()
}

positional_value("QB", 20)
positional_value(c("QB", "DT"), 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by myself (pretty proud to say the least)

```
positional_value <- function(position) {
  Redraft[ , "Position"] <- as.character(Redraft[,"Position" ])
  position <- deparse(substitute(position))
  first_100 <- Redraft %>% 
    select(Position, Pick) %>% 
    filter(Pick <= 100)
  first_100$pickvalue <- (((first_100$Pick * 100) / first_100$Pick) - first_100$Pick) + 1
  pick_total <- first_100 %>% 
    select(Position, pickvalue) %>% 
    filter(Position == position) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(pickvalue))
 return(pick_total)}
```

Comment: I was going to say that that was the error but then I realised that the formula is probably wrong: `(first_100$Pick * 100) / first_100$Pick)` is equal to `100`.